# Publish Windows App Sdk - SelfContained vs WindowsAppSDKSelfContained

Tags: windows, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

While Publishing app developed using 'Windows App Sdk', What is the difference between <SelfContained> vs <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>.

To reduce the app size, I want to set <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>false</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>. Will it require users to manually install windows app sdk on their system, or `Microsoft Store` app can automatically install the sdk as part of application installation?

Comment: Didn't know there was a just ``SelfContained`` option in **WinAppSDK**. Do you have any resources/links for that?

Comment: SelfContained is for .NET itself (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file), WindowsAppSDKSelfContained is for WinAppSDK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/self-contained-deploy/deploy-self-contained-apps) which requires SelfContained in the .NET case, I believe *".NET apps need to be published as self-contained as well to be fully self-contained. "*

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish 
 For setting PublishTrimmed=true, it requires to set SelfContained=true.

Comment: I guess trimming is [not stable](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2478) yet. I would skip this for the moment.